# i want to url rewrite

Tags: asp.net

I have a path which is http://www.infotrackls.com/PdfQuotation/Eng.pdf. I want to rewrite the give path into http://www.infotrackls.com/eng.
Would you help me?

web.config code is

```
 <urlrewrites>
          <rule>
            <url>Eng</url>
            <rewrite>/PdfQuotation/Eng.pdf</rewrite>
         </rule> </urlrewrites>
```

page code is

```
<a href ="Eng"> eng</a>
```

the all above code is run on local host but ths code is not run on the server.

Comment: http://www.infotrackls.com/PdfQuotation/Eng.pdf into http://www.infotrackls.com/eng

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** I have edited my answer as per your comment

I have a feeling that you are going around the problem the wrong way.

Since you want the user to know of the existence of http://www.infotrackls.com/eng , you should use that in your hyperlink.

So when the user clicks on the hyperlink, he would see http://www.infotrackls.com/eng in the address bar.

And to map **http://www.infotrackls.com/eng** to **http://www.infotrackls.com/PdfQuotation/Eng.pdf**, you should modify your **webconfig.** file as follows

```
<system.web>
   ...
    <urlMappings enabled="true">
        <add url="~/eng/" mappedUrl="~/PdfQuotation/eng.pdf" />
    </urlMappings>
   ...
</system.web>
```

Comment: dear sir, I have a folder which is "PdfQuotation" and also contains the file "Eng.pdf". When is use <ahref="PdfQuotation/End.Pdf">eng</a>. when i click on the end pdf open in the browsers with path "http://www.infotackls.com/PdfQuotation/Eng.pdf" but i want that the browser path should show like 'http://www.infotrackls.com/Eng' instead of "http://www.infotackls.com/PdfQuotation/Eng.pdf"